# redisplaying data from a table in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to redisplay the data from a table

currently the data in the table goes as

```
 __________________________________________
|                 UserMeta                 |
|__________________________________________|
| id | userID | orgID |  keyType | keyData |
|____|________|_______|__________|_________|
|  1 |      1 |     1 | UserName | Scarlet |
|  2 |      1 |     1 |      Age |      23 |
|  3 |      2 |     2 | UserName |   Diana |
|  4 |      2 |     2 |      Age |      27 |
|  5 |      3 |     1 | UserName |   Kevin |
|  6 |      3 |     1 |      Age |      18 |
|____|________|_______|__________|_________|
```

I'd like to be able to format it to the following

```
 _________________________________ 
|           vUserMeta             |
|_________________________________|
| UserID | orgID | UserName | Age |
|________|_______|__________|_____|
|      1 |     1 |  Scarlet |  23 |
|      2 |     2 |    Diana |  27 | 
|      3 |     1 |    Kevin |  18 |
|________|_______|__________|_____|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to join `UserMeta` on itself as follows:

```
SELECT u.userID  AS UserID,
       u.orgID   AS orgID,
       u.keyData AS UserName,
       v.keyData AS Age
FROM   UserMeta u
       JOIN UserMeta v
         ON u.userID = v.userID
            AND u.keyType = 'UserName'
            AND v.keyType = 'Age'
```